# Data changes automatically in array

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to execute a very simple piece of code.
But I am unable to find how the value of T[i][j] is changing all of a sudden.

### Code:-

```
void initialize(float** &T,int NP,int D,int low,int high)
{
    int i = 0,j = 0;

    T = (float **)malloc(NP*sizeof(float));

    for(i = 0;i<NP;i++)
    { 
        T[i] = (float *)malloc(D*sizeof(float));
        for(j = 0;j<D;j++)
        {
            T[i][j] = low + (high - low)*((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX);
            if(i==0)
            {
                printf("%p :\t",&T[i][j]);
                printf("%f\n",T[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    for(j = 0;j<D;j++)
    {
        printf("%p :\t",&T[0][j]);
        printf("%f\n",T[0][j]);

    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

### Main:-

```
float** T = NULL;
initialize(T,NP,D,low,high);
```

### OUTPUT:-

> 0x1fc5070 :   3.401877 0x1fc5074 :    -1.056171 0x1fc5078 :   2.830992
>   0x1fc507c :   2.984400 0x1fc5080 :    4.116474 0x1fc5084 :    -3.024486
>   0x1fc5088 :   -1.647773 0x1fc508c :   2.682296 0x1fc5090 :    -2.222253
>   0x1fc5094 :   0.539700
>
> 0x1fc5070 :   0.000000 0x1fc5074 :    0.000000 0x1fc5078 :    0.000000
>   0x1fc507c :   0.000000 0x1fc5080 :    0.000000 0x1fc5084 :    0.000000
>   0x1fc5088 :   0.000000 0x1fc508c :    0.000000 0x1fc5090 :    0.000000
>   0x1fc5094 :   0.000000

Comment: Which compiler are you using ? On gcc the program wouldn't even compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
T = (float **)malloc(NP*sizeof(float));
```

to:

```
T = (float **)malloc(NP*sizeof(float *));
```

Comment: Isn't `sizeof(float)` and `sizeof(float *)` same on a x86 machine ?

Comment: Who said he was on x86?  Anyways, it's the only bug that I could see in that program.

Comment: Got it. Removed the `C` Tag.